# Sprite Sheet Animation in DirectX11.0

Tags: animation, directx-11, sprite-sheet

Recently, I've taken up the construction of a 2-D rendering 'engine' of sorts based off: http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut11.html, but converted to use DirectX11.0.

The point of this 'engine' is to build a small 2-D game as a personal project, to gain more familiarity with the raw API -- meaning ***no*** outside libraries such as http://directxtk.codeplex.com/.

### My problem lies in the rendering of Sprite Sheet Animations.

Since I'm already using dynamic vertex buffers to re-position my images, I don't see the necessity of doing the transformations in the vertex shader, as detailed here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28287/how-to-set-sprite-source-coordinates.

So instead I opted for this solution:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{   //having not yet overloaded the operators, I have to be a barbarian.

    vertices[i].texture.x *= offset;
    vertices[i].texture.y *= offset;

    vertices[i].texture.x += offset * (tile % tiles_x);
    vertices[i].texture.y += offset * floorf(tile / tiles_x);

}
```

where `tile` is the *current* tile to render, and `tiles_x` is the *number* of tiles across the bitmap horizontally.

EDIT: `offset` is computed as `1.0f / tiles_x`

I believe the problem with this to be due to the fact that my Sprite Sheets are decidedly not square.

### My question is this: How, using only the D3D11 API, could I achieve drawing simply a section of a texture for animation?

Why just a section of a texture?

I'm loading the sheet from an .xml file containing the various Render Rectangles for the individual animation frames (Anchor Point Animation).

Swapping out the Render Rectangles should achieve what I'm after.

In addition to Sprite Animation, it could then be applied to very large backgrounds in which only the Section in view actually gets drawn.

Comment: Your example code doesn't make sense. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @RossRidge Theoretically, it's suppose to calculate texture offsets. For instance, if i had a sprite sheet [such as a bitmap font] and i wanted to render the image in the center, so I'd tell DirectX to draw just that portion of the texture. So if i had a Rectangle at { [100, 100], [150, 100], [100, 150], [150, 150] } { top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right }, I'd need to convert each of my 6  vertices to texture coordinates spanning 0 -> 1.

Comment: I'd assume its supposed set the texture coordinates so that correspond to one tile in the texture. So why is it trying to modify the coordinates already in stored in the vertices instead of just setting them to the correct values? Also you don't actually describe what your problem is. What output are you expecting and what are you getting instead?

Comment: @RossRidge I've already set the texture coordinates for each vertex so that a texture would stretch all the way across the surface. the modification of the texture coordinates is to only draw a portion instead. lets say [that this is my texture](https://10firstgames.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/actionstashhd.png), but adjusting the texture coordinates only zooms the image in.

Comment: Lets say you've actually written a program that uses the code you've written above. Lets say you run it. What do you see? What do you expect to see instead?

Comment: @RossRidge Like i said. modifying the texture coordinates stretched [zooms] the image across the quad. i expected to see the image un-stretched

Comment: That's what selecting one tile of a texture that's made up of multiple of tiles is supposed to do. Zoom in to one area of the texture, the area that makes up the tile, rather than displaying the entire texture.

Comment: @RossRidge correct. however, since the entire image blows up i'm thinking something's the matter. I believe the problem is in the vertices themselves. if i have a sprite that's 32 x 32 pixels, but the quad is say 100 x 100, then it's going to expand. so I think what i need to do is compute the size of the eventual render rectangle based on the UVs i need, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If you're expecting the texels to match up one to one to with pixels on the screen, then you need to set coordinates of the vertices accordingly. If the quad is 100x100 pixels on screen then the texture will fill that entire space regardless of what the texture coordinates are. The texture coordinates only select which part of the texture is used, not how much of each triangle gets filled in.  If your code is displaying the correct part of the texture, but it's too big on screen then the problem is with how you set your vertex coordinates, not with the texture coordinates.